# How to show error message inside the edit text in android?

Tags: android

I know this is very simple question,I am new to android
  for example: There are two edit text we can show hint like username and password if user doesn't enter anything then I want to show error message in place of Hint means inside the edit text .
  I have google but I got the tutorial where error message is floating on the tip or below . please guide me to show error message inside the edit text.

Comment: use hint and change hint color to red 
enter your number *

Answer (score 0):

you can try changing the hint dynamically

```
mEditText.setHint("Enter Proper Data");
```

additionally, you can also change the color of hint from the java so you can try that.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do 
just change the color of hint

```
editText.setHintTextColor(Color.RED);
editText.setHint("Error HINT");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like following and can also add the null case too. Where first_name is an editText

```
if(first_name.getText().length()==0 && first_name.getText().toString().isEmpty())
{
  //This is an error message and will show on EditText
   first_name.setError("Please Enter First Name"); 

}
```

It'll work for you.